# Issue downgrading kernel to 5.19.0-35 from 5.19.0-42 for Intel Arc GPU driver

Tags: linux-kernel, gpu, ubuntu-22.04

I am having issue downgrading the kernel 5.19.0-35 from 5.19.0-42 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Since Intel GPU doesn't support any other kernel, I need this specific kernel otherwise I am unable to boot the computer.
the errors are
**E: Unable to locate package linux-image-5.19.0-35-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-image-5.19.0-35-generic'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-5.19.0-35-generic'**

I have tried searching for linux package by using apt search linux-image.I also have tried 'ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh -r' to list all available Kernel and unable to find this specific kernel (5.19.0-35). Although, I can see other available kernel for exmaple 5.15.0.32 etc and am successfully able to switch to them. The problem is I dont find 5.19.0-35 anywhere. Even the launchpad site does not have package containing deb package for this kernel. Can someone please help with this. I am new to Ubuntu and have tried most of solution posted on askUbuntu and other sites.